# print preview cut from sides

Tags: html, css

hi i have this css code

```
@media print{
  body{
     width:100% !important;
  }
  table{max-width: 100% !important}
}
```

now if the scale in the print is 100%
the preview looks like this 
[image]
but if i change the scale to 120 or 130 % the page preview looks like this 
[image]
as you can see the table go to right and its not responsive 
thanks

Comment: So what were you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want the table to be responsive at print preview

Comment: to be 100% width not like the second image

Comment: Why worry? the printed result is not zoomable since it is on paper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the given style is the only style applied.

```
@media print{
  body{
     width:100vw !important;
  }
  table{max-width: 100vw !important}
}
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!